# Highlighting Links while using nav arrows

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, sliding

I have a question similar to others on here but those didn't help because they referred to list links while these are not lists.

I have a horizontally sliding site.  When you click the links at the top, they highlight according to what page it is sliding to.  However, if you use the left and right nav arrows, the links don't highlight properly.  It just stays highlightted on the last link that was clicked.  I was wondeering if anyone could show me what I am doing wrong. I want the correct link to be highlighted even when the nav arrows are being used.

Here is the script on jsfiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/LD9YS/13/

And here is one of my failed attempts... (please don't try to figure out what I was doing here... I have no idea of this myself)

```
$(".arrow-right").click(function(){
   prevA.removeClass("active");
   prevA = $(A[index]).addClass("active");
});
```

It's painfully obvious that I haven't the first clue how to do this but at least i gave it a few attempts.  I wanted to show more of my attempts but they were so obsurd that I can not even remember what I had done on those.

Can someone please help?  If someone can't help with this, Im ready to just give up on it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'd do that like so

```
$('.arrow-left').on('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('.tabs .active').prev().trigger('mousedown');
});

$('.arrow-right').on('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('.tabs .active').next().trigger('mousedown');
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/LD9YS/17/)

Comment: Works great but there is one small issue.  When it gets to the last link (page 5), and you keep clicking it, the highlighting keeps going round and round but the page stays on page 5.

To clarify, I set it so that the pages don't loop back to the first page.  I want it to stop on 5.

Comment: You ROCK!  A true professional if I ever saw one.  Thanks so much!  Works like a charm.

Comment: @user2284703 - I actually changed it, this seems much easier !

Comment: You could also easily join the two handlers like this -> **http://jsfiddle.net/LD9YS/18/**

Answer (score 0):

This would work for right arrow...

```
  $('.arrow-left').on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault()
    var current = $('.tabs').find('a.active').index();
      if(current!= $('.tabs').find('a:first').index()){
         $('.tabs a').removeClass('active');
          $('.tabs a').eq(current-1).addClass('active');
      }
    mySwiper.swipePrev()
  })
```

The same for left arrow

```
$('.arrow-right').on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault()
    var current = $('.tabs').find('a.active').index();
      if(current!= $('.tabs').find('a:last').index()){
         $('.tabs a').removeClass('active');
          $('.tabs a').eq(current+1).addClass('active');
      }
mySwiper.swipeNext()
})
```

Comment: This code just messed up all of my pages when using it.  I have each section (page) displaying an iframe but this code just made all of those into small iframes next to one another all in a row on one page.  Thanks though.  Appreciate the time to assist.

Comment: @user2284703 Perhaps I forgot to include the `)` at the end of the block. Now I edited it, but I'm glad you've found your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what you should do:

```
  $('.arrow-left').on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    mySwiper.swipePrev();
    $(".tabs .active").removeClass('active');
    $($('.tabs a')[mySwiper.activeIndex]).addClass('active');
  })

  $('.arrow-right').on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    mySwiper.swipeNext();
    $(".tabs .active").removeClass('active');
    $($('.tabs a')[mySwiper.activeIndex]).addClass('active');
  })
```